# Getting EX_BAD_ACCESS while printing object of CGImageRef

Tags: objective-c, ios7, cgimageref

In my app I am getting bed access error while printing the object of CGImageRef. So please look into my below code and help me out

```
- (CGImageRef)cachedImageForPageIndex:(NSUInteger)pageIndex {
NSNumber *pageIndexNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:pageIndex];
UIImage *pageImage;
@synchronized (self.pageCache) {
    pageImage = [self.pageCache objectForKey:pageIndexNumber];
}
if (!pageImage) {
   // CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageRetain([pageImage CGImage]);
    CGImageRef pageCGImage = CGImageRetain([self imageForPageIndex:pageIndex]);  //[self imageForPageIndex:pageIndex];
    if (pageCGImage) {
        pageImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:pageCGImage];
        @synchronized (self.pageCache) {
            [self.pageCache setObject:pageImage forKey:pageIndexNumber];
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"image = %@",[pageImage CGImage]);
return pageImage.CGImage;}
```

Comment: I have just managed to resolved this. Follow this link:

[Solution for LeavesCache.m having EXC_BAD_ACCESS][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055482/leavescache-m-works-on-simulator-but-not-on-device/27057802#27057802